# Ruby 'is_a?' class or module required (TypeError)

Tags: ruby, while-loop, integer, conditional-statements, typeerror

I'm playing around with Ruby and trying create a little bank account program.  When I run this particular line of code which is running withing the create_account:

```
unless @response.is_a? Integer && @response.to_str.length == 4
    puts "Your response must be 4 numbers in length."
    create_account
else
    @pin = @response
    puts "Your pin has been set."
end
```

I get this response:

```
bank_account.rb:24:in 'is_a?':class or module required (TypeError)
    from bank_account.rb:24:in 'create_account'
    from bank_account.rb:47:in '<main>'
```

I can't exactly figure out what's going on, but I'm including the rest of my code.  It's incomplete, obviously because I'm stuck on this part.  I go through a while loop and enter 'Create Account' to start the create_account method.  My goal is to run the conditional and require the user to type a 4 digit integer, like any ole pin number.  If it is not an integer nor 4 digits in length, I call the create_account method to get them to start over.

I'm running ruby 2.0.0 if that information is necessary, but I wager it is likely more to do with my code.  Stackoverflow is new to me, so I apologize if this question has been asked.  I tried to do my homework as is advised before asking a question, but I'm still stumped.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You need to put the class `Integer` in parentheses:

```
unless @response.is_a?(Integer) && @response.to_str.length == 4
```

You are actually evaulating `is_a?` on `(Integer && @response.to_str.length == 4)` which is a boolean value, not a class or module.

Comment: I did not realize that it was including the entire second half of the conditional if I didn't specifically put the class in parentheses.  Thank you.  I still can't get it to accept something that's four numbers in length for some reason, but one problem at a time.

Comment: @MarkHJr, if `@response` is indeed an `Integer`, then you can't call `to_str` on it, only `to_s`. When I try your test in the console with value `454524` I get this message: `NoMethodError: undefined method `to_str' for 454524:Fixnum`.

Comment: good answer and explanation!  Solved my problem real fast when it could have taken much longer.  +1