# Parens required or Ruby says: TypeError (class or module required) ... why?

Tags: ruby, typeerror, operator-precedence

I'm trying this in `irb`, Ruby version 3:

```rb
3.0.0 :001 > num = 42
 => 42 
3.0.0 :002 > num.is_a?(Integer) && num > 10
 => true 
3.0.0 :003 > num.is_a? Integer && num > 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from /Users/kai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        4: from /Users/kai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        3: from /Users/kai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/irb-1.3.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from (irb):3:in `<main>'
        1: from (irb):3:in `is_a?'
TypeError (class or module required)
```

Why do I need the parentheses here:

```
v.is_a?(Integer)
```

?

How does the operator precedence work?

And why does Ruby generate such an arcane error message in this scenario?

With some digging I find the question answered previously here:
[Ruby 'is_a?' class or module required (TypeError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23372692/ruby-is-a-class-or-module-required-typeerror)

and the fundamental issue addressed here:
[What's the precedence of method calls with and without parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41313154/whats-the-precedence-of-method-calls-with-and-without-parentheses)

which reference the official Ruby documentation:
https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html

But I don't feel all my questions are answered.  Anyone care to wrap all of this up cleanly?

Comment: Always use args with brackets. This is more understandable to both other developer and Ruby parser. That's it

Comment: The method call has a lower precedence than `&&` so `num.is_a? Integer && num > 10` is `num.is_a?(Integer && num > 10)` then you end up passing a boolean to `#is_a?` when it expects a `Module`.

Comment: I'm sure Rubocop would have prevented this error, but it was not active in the environment in which I was coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do I need the parentheses here:
>
> `v.is_a?(Integer)`

You need the parenthesis to specify what you are passing to the `is_a?` method. Without them, Ruby evaluates the entire `Integer && num > 10` expression and passes *that* to the method.

> How does the operator precedence work?

`is_a?` isn't an operator, so there's no precedence for it to follow. Expressions are evaluated before being passed to methods, that's all that's happening.

> And why does Ruby generate such an arcane error message in this scenario?

Ruby is evaluating the expression `Integer && num > 10` which gives `true`. This value is then being passed to `num.is_a?`. `is_a?` then gives a `TypeError` as it expects a class or module, not a boolean.